# Merge array based on specified element value - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays, each consisting of 3 values,

```
[owner, registered_user, license_type]
```

Here's some sample data:

```
[["john", "john", "drivers license"],["john", "john", "boat license"],
["john", "ryan", "drivers license"], ["john", "ryan", "boat license"],
["Sam", "Sam", "drivers license"],["Sam", "Sam", "boat license"],
["Sam", "Tim", "drivers license"], ["Sam", "Tim", "boat license"]]
```

I am looking for some way to merge this data to remove the duplicates and end up with something like this:

```
=> { "john"=>{
            "john"=>["drivers license", "boat license"],
            "ryan"=>["drivers license", "boat license"]
          },
  "Sam" =>{
            "Sam" =>["drivers license", "boat license"],
            "Tim" =>["drivers license", "boat license"]
          }
}
```

Sorry if any of this is syntactically incorrect or invalid Ruby, I'm new and not sure how to format this correctly.

Comment: Your expected result in a mess.

Comment: Please edit to make your desired result a valid Ruby object.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about the formatting, the output from @CarySwoveland's answer is exactly what I was after so I've edited to incorporate that. Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using recursion one can have any number of nested levels. I have initially assumed the result to be a nested array.

**Return a nested array**

```
def rearrange(arr)
  return arr.flatten if arr.first.size == 1
  arr.group_by(&:first).map { |f,a| [f, rearrange(a.map { |b| b.drop 1 })] }
end

arr = [["john", "john", "drivers license"], ["john", "john", "boat license"],
       ["john", "ryan", "drivers license"], ["john", "ryan", "boat license"],
       ["Sam",   "Sam", "drivers license"], ["Sam",   "Sam", "boat license"],
       ["Sam",   "Tim", "drivers license"], ["Sam",   "Tim", "boat license"]]

rearrange arr
  #=> [
  #     ["john", [
  #                ["john", ["drivers license", "boat license"]],
  #                ["ryan", ["drivers license", "boat license"]]
  #              ]
  #     ],
  #     ["Sam",  [
  #                ["Sam", ["drivers license", "boat license"]],
  #                ["Tim", ["drivers license", "boat license"]]
  #              ]
  #     ]
  #   ]
```

**Return a nested hash**

The OP should consider returning a hash, which would make it easier to extract information. That can be done as follows, again using recursion.

```
def rearrange(arr)
  return arr.flatten if arr.first.size == 1
  h = arr.group_by(&:first)
  h.each_key { |k| h[k] =  { |_,a| [f, rearrange(a.map { |b| b.drop 1 })] }
end

h = rearrange(arr)
  #=> { "john"=>{
  #               "john"=>["drivers license", "boat license"],
  #               "ryan"=>["drivers license", "boat license"]
  #             },
  #     "Sam" =>{
  #               "Sam" =>["drivers license", "boat license"],
  #               "Tim" =>["drivers license", "boat license"]
  #             }
  #   }
```

By returning a hash you can easily retrieve data of interest. For example,

```
h["Sam"]["Tim"]
  #=> ["drivers license", "boat license"]
```